# How long should a Windows Server 2008 R2 install spend at "expanding Windows Files"

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I'm currently installing Windows Server 2008 R2 on a newly built computer. The system does meet the minimum requirements. It seems to take forever on the "expanding windows files" section. I've left it run for an hour and it hasn't moved beyond 0%.

A test shows that both Windows XP and Fedora 10 install successfully on the same system. The Server 2008 R2 is downloaded from Microsoft Dreamspark.

The system has a Core 2 Quad Q8300, and 2GB of RAM.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on a resonably fast system the entire installation shouldn't take much longer than 20 minutes.

did you try another DVD? does the same happen when you install from USB (e.g. via WinToFlash)?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on your install media and hard drive speeds. I would estimate anywhere from 2-30 minutes.

Comment: Right, so an hour at 0% is clearly a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Burned a new disk, problem solved. Oops.